# Loop data search in FoxPro

Tags: for-loop, while-loop

I have a table name " Prod_Master" where some different uniq data in column "Item" (e,g 111, 178, 19024 . .). Now I want to brows these data from another table name "Item_Master" where the same value in same column name "Item" one by one (with loop program). This brows program will continue till the end of last record of "Prod_Master".

Select a
Use Prod_Master
m.code= Item
Use Item_Master
Brow for item=code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's see if I understand your question correctly... In table Prod_Master you have a field named "Item".  You also have a table "Item_Master" with a field that is also named "Item".

Assuming this is correct, your question if I am understanding you correctly, is to "loop" through all of the records in the Prod_Master table and display a BROWSE window in Item_Master for each matching record in Prod_Master.

One option would be to write a short program as follows:

```
select item from prod_master into cursor tCursor
select('tCursor')
scan
  select * from item_master where item_master.item == prod_master.item into cursor tQuery
  select('tQuery')
  browse
  select('tCursor')
endscan
```

It is possible to have the second select statement in the item_master table display the browse window directly without having to store the data in tQuery but this solution gives you more control over the Item_master table if needed (for example make it ReadWrite and modify the data in just one column.

Please remember to accept this answer if it helps.